# How to handle assets in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, assets, webpack-encore

I am building an application with `Symfony 4` and I'd like to follow the [best practices for web assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html). I use Encore/Webpack for SCSS and JS and it works well; the resulting JS+CSS are nicely stored in /public/build folder. I'm stuck at how to store and use static assets like images, movies, sounds.

**Should images be stored in 'public/images' folder or in 'assets/images'?**

And some followup questions:

If the images are stored in `public/images`, will I get any benefit if I pollute the templates with `asset('...')` calls?

If the images are stored in `assets/images`, then:

- How are they moved into `public/images` to be served via http? `./bin/console assets:install` did nothing, saying: *'[OK] No assets were provided by any bundle.'*.
- How do I use them in SCSS? Via relative paths?

Regards,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Should images be stored in 'public/images' folder or in 'assets/images'?

Everything in `public/` is available through the browser. In here, only production ready and build things should be put.
As your images don't need any processing (I assume), you can (*should*) indeed put the images there.

Now, assume you're needing to do some processing (e.g. ugly JPEG compression), you would put the images in `assets/`, do some processing and then put only the processed images in `public/`.

> If the images are stored in public/images, will I get any benefit if I pollute the templates with asset('...') calls?

Yes, `asset()` doesn't have anything to do with Encore or asset build management. The only thing it does is fixing your URLs. This means that if you move your app to sub directories on your server (`example.com/app/`), the URLs will automatically adapt. Read more about it in the [Asset component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset) documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Another good way to reference images with `asset()` method in Symfony 4 is copying images in `public/build` when building assets with Encore.

## Use copyFiles() in Webpack Encore

Webpack Encore provides a function to copy your images on the public directory to allow `asset()` to access those files : [copyFiles()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/copy-files.html).

In your `webpack.config.js`

```
Encore.
...
.copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
    })
```

## Error: Encore.copyFiles is not a recognized property or method.

Please by sure that you are actualy using `symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` and not 
`symfony/webpack-encore-pack` as described [here](https://symfony.com/blog/encore-0-21-0-webpack-4-support-copy-files-support-webpackencorebundle#ready-to-upgrade).

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
composer remove symfony/webpack-encore-pack
yarn install
yarn upgrade
yarn run watch
```

My `package.json`

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.22.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
        "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer since Oct 19 '18 when this feature has been merged https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/pull/409

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit webpack.config.js after

   Encore
      .setOutputPath('../build/')
2. Add the following lines. You can also do more configuration by uncommenting the lines

   ```
   .enableVersioning()
   .copyFiles({
    from: './assets/images',

    // optional target path, relative to the output dir
    to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',

    // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
    //to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',

    // only copy files matching this pattern
    //pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
   })
   ```
3. Now you can use image by

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/copy-files.html
Details: http://toihid.com/?p=332